# Nested DIV's across functions in PHP, do not seem to work

Tags: plugins, php, functions

My parent function (`vc_make_graph()`), which has main 'PArent DIV', calls several child functions as shown below. Each child functions also has corresponding DIV's - which I am assuming should be logically children of the DIV in the parent.

I would like to enclose all objects from within my child functions into a Box defined by the main DIV ('oveall') in the parent function (`vc_make_graph()`). The problem is that the DIV in the parent ('overall') does not seem to enclose DIV's in child functions inside it. PHP Code, CSS and Screen Shot is below. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
<style>
<?php include 'style.css'; ?>
</style>

<?php 


class DBController 
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "vro";
    private $conn;

    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() 
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }

    function runQuery($query) 
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
        {
            return $resultset;
        }
        else
        {
            return False;
        }

    }

    function numRows($query) 
    {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}

function vc_make_graph()
{       
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    # Show the customer dropdown
?>  
    <div id="overall">
    <?php
    $results = show_customer_dropdown($db_handle);
    if (isset($results))
        if (!results)
            return '<h6>Database query NOT successful!</h6><br/>';
    # Show dates
    show_dates();
    show_cars();
?>
</div>
<?php
    show_pushbuttons(); 
}
add_shortcode('make_graph', 'vc_make_graph');


function show_customer_dropdown($handle)
{
    $query = 'SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, LastName FROM customers ORDER BY FirstName, LastName';
    $results = $handle->runQuery($query);
    if (!$results)
        return False;
    ?>
    <div class="inputs">
        <div class="lables">Customer:</div>
            <select name="user" id="user-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="get_car(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select User</option>
        <?php
        foreach($results as $user)
        {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $user["CustomerID"]; ?>"><?php echo $user["FirstName"] . " " . $user["LastName"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<?php
} 
?>
<?php

function show_dates()
{
?>

    <div class="inputs">
        <div class="lables">
            From Date:
        </div>
        <input type="date" name="fromdate" id = "datepicker1"><br>
        <div class="lables">
            To Date:
        </div>
        <input type="date" name="todate" id = "datepicker2">
    </div>
<?php
}

function show_cars()
{
?>
    <div class="inputs">
        <div class="lables">Select Car:</div>
            <select name="car" id="car-list" class="demoInputBox">
            <option value="">Select Car</option>
            </select>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
function get_car($id)
{ 
    alert($id);
}
</script>

<?php

function show_pushbuttons()
{

}
```

CSS is below:

```
.lables
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.inputs
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 33%;
    min-width:200px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#overall
{
    border-color: #686363;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't both echo and return stuff in a function at the same time. Your `vc_make_graph()` outputs some DIV, then returns a value. When you use return, the rest of your code will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` command does exactly what it says, it *returns* the data and then returns back to the script. So, any lines after it will not be executed.

You have this function in your code:

```
function vc_make_graph() {       
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    # Show the customer dropdown ?>  
    <div id="overall"><?php
        $results = show_customer_dropdown($db_handle);
        if (isset($results))
            if (!results)
                return '<h6>Database query NOT successful!</h6><br/>';
        # Show dates
        show_dates();
        show_cars();?>
    </div><?php
    show_pushbuttons(); 
}
```

Let's say the result is false, and the conditional is triggered. You will have this HTML output:

```
<div id="overall">
```

Which is an open DIV without a closing tag. This will mess up with the rest of the structure. Instead of return, use echo.